# Agreement between a non-Islamic State with an Islamic state?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-government

I understand that a non-Islamic state could come to a agreement with a Islamic state near to it. It's in Quran as I heard.

So could somebody please explain more about it. What are the conditions that both Islamic state and non-Islamic sate contribute together to peace between each two?

Answer (score 2):

Peace is the foundation of Islam's international law. Please consider the following verse:

> **Then if they should be inclined to make peace, make peace with them,**
>   and put your trust in God. Surely, it is He who is All Hearing and All
>   Knowing. **Should they seek to deceive you, God is enough for you**: it
>   was He who strengthened you with His help, and rallied the faithful
>   around you, and bound their hearts together. (8:61-62)

- Just before this verse, God is encouraging Muslims to prepare for war.
  Even then He says that if peace is an option go for it.
- Peace is desirable even if Muslims are doubtful of the motives of the other side. They should trust God and go for it.

They can come to an agreement on any conditions they agree to. After that it becomes a religious obligation to fulfill them:

> Keep your promises; you will be called to account for every promise
>   which you have made! (17:34)

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, two condition must be met before war is permitted:

1. lack of treaty
2. breach of treaty

If there is no treaty between two nations, then war against that nation (group of people) is an acceptable policy in Islam, but if the opposition seeks to negotiate a treaty, then negotiation is advised.

If there is a treaty already in place, and the other nation breaches its regulations, then once again, war against that nation (group of people) is acceptable, but if the other nation decides to negotiate a new treaty, then negotiation is advise.

Peaceful interaction between an Islamic State and an unIslamic State is through a treaty.

The above information is extracted from Quran and Ahadith in their context.